# C# Punch In Punch Out Using DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, time

I have tried to create a simple time calculator when the user clicks Punch In then Punch Out.  I have created variables for each using DateTime.Now to capture the actual time when the user punches in and out.  I have also created a button for punch in, and a separate button for punch out.  For some reason, when I click Punch In, then wait a minute or two to test it, when I click Punch Out, the Punch Out displays the same time as the Punch In.  What am I doing wrong?
Below is the code:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnPunchIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            string punchIn = startTime.ToShortTimeString();
            lblPunchInTime.Text = punchIn.ToString();
        }

        private void btnPunchOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string punchOut = stopTime.ToShortTimeString();
            TimeSpan timeWorked = new TimeSpan();
            lblPunchOutTime.Text = punchOut.ToString();
            timeWorked = stopTime - startTime;
            lblTimeWorked.Text = timeWorked.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only time you set `stopTime` is when your form is created (at the top of your Form class). So it will always be equal to that time.

I think you mean to set `stopTime = DateTime.Now` at the time they click the button. Similar deal for `startTime`.

Answer (score 1):

You are only ever assigning values to `startTime` and `stopTime` once, when the `Form1` instance is constructed. And they are both being assigned (almost) the same time value, which is the current local time.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the start and end times to DateTime.Now when the class is initialized.  If you set them in the event handlers, you should be all set.